# Unable to install drcsim and gazebo on Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10

Tags: gazebo, installation, drcsim, ubuntu

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When i try to install drcsim, gazebo, or ros i get the following errors on both Ubuntu 12.04 as well as 12.10. I have tried multiple times to install and have the followed the directions on the site. I get the following errors when i try.

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 drcsim : Depends: gazebo (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: ros-fuerte-pr2-mechanism but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: ros-fuerte-std-msgs but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: ros-fuerte-common-msgs but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: ros-fuerte-image-common but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: ros-fuerte-pr2-controllers but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-experimental but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model-visualization but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/358/unable-to-install-drcsim-and-gazebo-on-ubuntu-12.04-or-12.10/) by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-12-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-12-04**:
If you put the errors in code formatting (see the 010101 icon above the edit box) they'll be easier to read.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2012-12-05**:
can you post the console output when you run 'sudo apt-get -f`, thanks.

**Comment by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on 2012-12-05**:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or b

**Comment by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on 2012-12-05**:
basically i get the same exact error message that i do when i try to do sudo apt-get install drcsim.... the sudo apt-get install -f drcsim gives me the same message

**Comment by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on 2012-12-05**:
basically i get the same exact error message that i do when i try to do sudo apt-get install drcsim.... the sudo apt-get install -f drcsim gives me the same message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Okay, I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 for the 7th time. Retried. And it works. It crashes often but it does launch, and I can place a model on the simulation. With a completely, fresh install, I was able to download the drcsim using "sudo apt-get install drcsim" and it offered no problems. The only difficulty I encountered was that I had to add a source pointer to gazebo-1.3/setup.sh before the one to the drcsim/setup.h in the ~/.bashrc file. Without it it would give an error. As soon as I placed it before the drcsim/setup.sh source, it will launch and run, though it still crashes but for other reasons I presume.

Thank you all for trying to help me. I really appreciate it.

---

Originally posted by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) with karma: 48 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I noticed after giving up on 12.10, and installing 12.04 that on 12.10, when doing the "apt-get update" it never lists the ROS sources as it does in 12.04. Is it possible that in 12.10, the update command isn't behaving as expected?

I'm not too familiar with apt, is it possible to force it to do an update on just those sources?

---

Originally posted by [RonJ](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/112/ronj/) with karma: 21 on 2012-12-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1